# jQuery - If first element has class then Function

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to add a piece of code sitewide to affect all of my pages.

Right now, it goes something like this.

```
if($('#container > div:first').attr('id') == 'filterOptions') {
  $('#container').prepend('<div class="banner"></div>');
}
```

**The output:**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="banner"></div>
  <div id="filterOptions"><div>
</div>
```

**Example**, if the container looked like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="existingBanner"></div>
  <div id="filterOptions"><div>
</div>
```

Nothing would happen as the first div doesn't have the filterOptions ID.

Now I've hit a bump as I also have something that looks like this that the banner DOES get added to

```
<div id="container">
  <a class="existingBanner" href="#"></a>
  <div id="filterOptions"><div>
</div>
```

This will essentially have a double banner which is something I want to avoid.  because it's an anchor instead of a div.

So my question is.  instead of targeting **div:first** how would I target ALL elements?

**Something like...**

`if($('#container >` **any**`:first').attr('id') == 'filterOptions') { ... }`

Comment: Have you tried `$('#container > *:first').attr('id')` || `$('#container > :first').attr('id')`?

Comment: why you dont ask if exist `.existingBanner` class instead of first element of div?

Comment: @JuandeParras I work in a large team and where I know all of my banners have the same class, I know the rest of my team use their own classes and ID's.  So this is a workout really

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use the [All Selector (`*`)](https://api.jquery.com/all-selector/)

```
if($('#container > *:first').attr('id') == 'filterOptions') {
  $('#container').prepend('<div class="banner"></div>');
}
```

or you can use the functional approach:

```
// with hoisting
var $container = $('#container');
if($container.children().first().attr('id') == 'filterOptions') {
  $container.prepend('<div class="banner"></div>');
}
```

---

You could also flip the logic around:

```
// filterOptions is the first child:
if ( $('#filterOptions').prev().length === 0 ) {
    $('container').prepend('<div class="banner"></div>')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#container > div:first-child').attr('id') == 'filterOptions') {
  $('#container').prepend('<div class="banner">111111111</div>');
}
```

So, just change 'first' to first-child'.http://jsfiddle.net/un3opbsh/

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use any tag with filterOptions ID `#filterOptions`

You should you find filterOptions in `children()`

```
var $container = $('#container');
if($container.children().attr('#filterOptions') === "filterOptions") {
     $container.prepend('<div class="banner"></div>');
}
```

Using this if `#filterOptions` is any where it will work with any tag not just div.

Hope it will help you.